# Airmedia on Ubuntu

Tags: monitor, multimedia, media, screencast

Hi i am using Ubuntu 18 and need [Airmedia](https://www.crestron.com/en-US/Products/Featured-Solutions/Airmedia) to connect to a monitor at our office, I can't seem to find a Linux client, is there anything that will suit this need?

Thanks

Comment: In the website they say "connect from any browser on any network" so supposedly it needs no other client software? They also mention that it's OS independent which reinforces the previous idea. So, in all likelihood, the product is used the same way you would do in Windows.

Comment: You need the installer, there is one for windows and one for mac, nothing for Linux